# Навигация по блокам

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет. В очередной вечер я начинаю тупить, что даже не могу реализовать очевидное.

Есть 3 формы на одной странице: Вход/Регистрация/Восстановить. Мне необходимо скрывать формы по одной в зависимости от выбранной.

Изначально всё

```
$('#forgot').hide();
$('#signup').hide();
$('#login').show();
```

При клике на "ссылку", к примеру, на `app.com/#signup`, появляется форма регистрации, все остальные скрываются, ну и так далее.

В общем, всё предельно просто, но у меня не получается и даже стыдно писать такие вопросы. :[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var unionSelector = '#forgot, #signup, #login';
var $forms = $(unionSelector);
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function () { // у jQuery, насколько знаю, нет обработчика hashchange в обычной версии
    $forms.each(function () {
        var $form = $(this);
        if ($form.is(location.hash)) {
            $form.show();
        } else {
            $form.hide();
        }
    });
}, false);
```

**Обновление**

```
`$('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Сделайте для ссылок общий класс / роль, выбирайте их так же, и так же по ним проходить, сравнивая `.attr('href')` c `location.hash`. А еще лучше им задать какие-нибудь `data-form-id="1"` и искать по ним, в этом случае хэш вообще не будет нужен.

**Обновление**

```
$('li.active').removeClass('active');
```

Comment: @Etki hashchange подключен.

Можно как то сделать что бы js код работал везде, в любом участке html кода, потому что у меня работает он только возле </body> что очень странно

Comment: @Etki там не ссылкам класс присваивается просто, я просто забыл

  <li role="presentation"><a href="#signup">Регистрация</a></li>

Comment: @Bastian, `$('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').parent().addClass('active');`

Comment: @Etki уже понял, спасибо. Сделай комментарий ответом :]